# Qt QNetworkAccessManager why i can’t send more then 1 http request in parallel in the same main thread

Tags: c++, qt

I just noticed that when I try to send http request while there are already http requests
going on in the background, one of them stops and waits until the previous one will finish. They both use their own QNetworkAccessManagers. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

**UPDATE**
i must doing here something wrong and i don't know , here some code .
there are 2 http post functions the first is simple post that invoked every 5 sec
and the second one is file upload post function that call in parallel.
when i call the file upload the first stops , whits until the file upload finished and   continue this is come's from Qt with out my intervention  .
this is with single QNetworkAccessManager

```
    //Init in the class contractor

     networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this); 
     connect(networkManager,SIGNAL(sslErrors(QNetworkReply*,QList<QSslError>)), this, SLOT(on_sslErr(QNetworkReply*,QList<QSslError>)));


    //-----------------------------------------------------\\

    //this is upload file code , its taking time untill it finish working great

    PostImageRequest( QString& Response,
                                    QMap<QString,QString> paramsToPostMap,
                                    QString& BaseUrl,
                                    QString imageFullPath,
                                    int iTimeOutInterval)


    QByteArray imageFormat = QImageReader::imageFormat(imageFullPath);
    QString imageMimeType(imageFormat);
    QNetworkRequest request;
    QUrl params;
    QMapIterator<QString,QString> i(paramsToPostMap);
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        i.next();
        addField(i.key(),i.value());
    }

      addFile("file",imageFullPath,imageMimeType);
      QString crlf="\r\n";
      qsrand(QDateTime::currentDateTime().toTime_t());
      QString b=QVariant(qrand()).toString()+QVariant(qrand()).toString()+QVariant(qrand()).toString();
      QString boundary="---------------------------"+b;
      QString endBoundary=crlf+"--"+boundary+"--"+crlf;
      QString contentType="multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary;
      boundary="--"+boundary+crlf;
      QByteArray bond=boundary.toAscii();
      QByteArray send;
      bool first=true;

      for (int i=0; i<fieldNames.size(); i++) {
        send.append(bond);
        if (first) {
          boundary=crlf+boundary;
          bond=boundary.toAscii();
          first=false;
        }
        send.append(QString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\""+fieldNames.at(i)+"\""+crlf).toAscii());
        if (encodingS=="utf-8") send.append(QString("Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit"+crlf).toAscii());
        send.append(crlf.toAscii());
        send.append(strToEnc(fieldValues.at(i)));
      }
      for (int i=0; i<files.size(); i++) {
        send.append(bond);
        send.append(QString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\""+fileFieldNames.at(i)+"\"; filename=\""+fileNames.at(i)+"\""+crlf).toAscii());
        send.append(QString("Content-Type: "+fileMimes.at(i)+crlf+crlf).toAscii());
        send.append(files.at(i));  
      }

      send.append(endBoundary.toAscii());

      fieldNames.clear();
      fieldValues.clear();
      fileFieldNames.clear();
      fileNames.clear();
      fileMimes.clear();
      files.clear();
     request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, contentType.toAscii());
 request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentLengthHeader, QVariant(send.size()).toString());
     request.setUrl(BaseUrl);


     if(iTimeOutInterval != -1)
     {
         QEventLoop loop2;
         QTimer::singleShot(iTimeOutInterval, &loop2, SLOT(quit()) );
         loop2.exec();
 }
     QEventLoop loop;
     QNetworkReply *reply = networkManager->post(request,send);
     connect(reply, SIGNAL(uploadProgress(qint64,qint64)), this,SLOT(SetProgress(qint64,qint64)));
     connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
 loop.exec();       
     //return response 
     QNetworkReply::NetworkError networkError = reply->error();
     HandleNetworkError(networkError); 
     Response.clear();
     QByteArray data=reply->readAll();
     Response.append(data);
     //delete reply;
     reply->deleteLater();

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------\\

//this is the post function that invoket every 5 secound

    PostRequest(QString& Response,
                            QMap<QString,QString> paramsToPostMap,
                            QString& BaseUrl,
                            int iTimeOutInterval)


     QNetworkRequest request;
     QUrl params;
     QMapIterator<QString,QString> i(paramsToPostMap);
     while (i.hasNext()) {
        i.next();
        params.addQueryItem(i.key(),i.value());
     }
     request.setUrl(BaseUrl);

     QByteArray postArgs;
     postArgs = params.encodedQuery();

     if(iTimeOutInterval != -1)
     {
         QEventLoop loop2;
         QTimer::singleShot(iTimeOutInterval, &loop2, SLOT(quit()) );
         loop2.exec();
 }
     QEventLoop loop;
     QNetworkReply *reply = networkManager->post(request,postArgs);
     connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
 loop.exec();       
     //return response 
     QNetworkReply::NetworkError networkError = reply->error();
     HandleNetworkError(networkError); 
     Response.clear();
     QByteArray data=reply->readAll();
     Response.append(data);


     //delete reply;
     reply->deleteLater();
```

Comment: And don't use multiple instances of QNetworkAccessManager. It's designed to be shared and having multiple instances is expensive.

Comment: From the Qt 4.7 reference:

QNetworkAccessManager queues the requests it receives. The number of requests executed in parallel is dependent on the protocol. Currently, for the HTTP protocol on desktop platforms, 6 requests are executed in parallel for one host/port combination.

Comment: @Purnima: You can post the link to the doccumentation and post it as an answer, I think it answers the Question. Oh If you did so, You would have my upvote. :)

Comment: im defiantly doing here something wrong im posing my http request code
it is inside a singleton class

Comment: I think you need to create a minimum version of code recreating your problem, the code now seems to be too complicated.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Qt 4.7 reference](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qnetworkaccessmanager.html):

QNetworkAccessManager queues the requests it receives. The number of requests executed in parallel is dependent on the protocol. Currently, for the HTTP protocol on desktop platforms, 6 requests are executed in parallel for one host/port combination.

Comment: i know this but i have less then 6